# inserting string into Soapclient

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Well as the question says am trying to insert a string value into a Soapclient request I know there should be some sort of term before the $searchTerm parameter, but I don't have a clue what it is any help would be much appreciated.

```
$searchTerm = $_GET['search'];
$client = new SoapClient('http://stuiis.cms.gre.ac.uk/dd615/' .
    'aspweb/WatCoursework/Service.asmx?WSDL');
$xmlString = $client->getMusicdetailsSql()->getMusicdetailsSqlResult->$searchTerm;
```

Comment: I get nothing no error message, no data, I echo out the term to make sure it is present and it is

Comment: but when I use the term any, it comes back with the entire table

Comment: I've been able to get it to work and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$searchTerm = $_GET['search']; // try searching for "Dixon";
$client = new SoapClient('http://stuiis.cms.gre.ac.uk/dd615/' . 
                         'aspweb/WatCoursework/Service.asmx?WSDL');
$response = $client->getMusicdetailsSql(array('searchTerm'=>$searchTerm));
echo $response->getMusicdetailsSqlResult->any;
```

At this point you'll need to parse the XML and go on from there.  Its sometimes helpful to experiment and read out the value being stored in a variable to see what you can do with it.  Try running the following to see more details about whats possible:

```
print_r($client->getMusicdetailsSql());
print_r($client->getMusicdetailsSql(array('searchTerm'=>$searchTerm)));
...
```

Comment: thanks for the help and the advice I will definitely look at the results of the second section of code and keep your advice in mind next time I have any problem >_<